# Duplicate entries created on ManyToOne/OneToMany relationship when saving a new entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Running Spring 4.1.4 / Hibernate Entity Manager 4.1.8 / Spring JPA 2.1 on Tomcat 8 with MySQL 5.6.

I have two entities. Let's call them Person and Widget.

Person class:

```
@Entity(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    //... Other properties omitted    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Widget> widgets = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Widget> getWidgets() {
        return widgets;
    }
    public void setWidgets(Set<Widget> widgets) {
        this.widgets = widgets;
    }
    public boolean addWidget(Widget widget) {
        return this.widgets.add(widget);
    }

    //...other getters/setters omitted
}

@Entity(name = "widget")
public class Widget {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "part_id")
    private String partId;
    //... Other properties omitted    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
    //...getters/setters omitted
}
```

I have the two DB tables set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `widget` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `status_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `widgets_ix1` (`part_id`,`active`),
  --some properties omitted
  KEY `widgets_fk1` (`person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `person_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) --Some irrelevant details omitted

CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
--some properties omitted
  `status_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `create_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Now for the issue.

I have a restlet call that calls into a @Transactional service. The service creates a new Widget. Sets some properties and tries to add it to the Person via addWidget(...). Then I call another service method that only does a saveAndFlush().

When the service returns to the restlet, a commit happens but this triggers a second insert into the widget table. (Which has a unique constraint on the part_id + active fields). I cannot figure out, for my life, why this is happening. I've tried just about every possible combination of saving and flushing the person, the widget, both, flushing before, flushing after, default properties. I think I am now so flummoxed that I cannot see straight to the heart of this issue.

The transaction starts in the service method and ends when the service method ends. (The only propagation is the default REQUIRED). There is no worry of multiple access so concurrency isn't the issue.

Here is the logic surrounding the call to the service method.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Message updateWidgetAdd(WidgetUpdateRequest message) {
    //Validation
    Person person = personService.findById(message.getPersonId());
    try {
        Widget widget = new Widget();
        widget.setPartId(message.getPartId().toLowerCase());
        widget.setActive(true);
        widget.setPerson(person);
        person.addWidget(widget);
        personService.save(person);
        return createSuccessPayload("id", widget.getId(), "partId", widget.getPartId());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return createFailure("Uh oh.");
    }
}
```

I am utterly stumped. Any advice/help is welcome!

Comment: Can you check the no of widget or widget details before save?

Comment: What is this?  public void setWidgets(Set<Device> widgets)

Comment: @Alan a simple transcription error. The names of the classes were changed to protect my client; but apparently I missed one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can close this issue. I found the problem.

NB: When looking for issues lower in the code, ensure that the issue isn't something simple; such as accidentally making two restlet calls in quick succession because you accidentally call the ajax javascript function (added to a button) twice.

Answer (score 0):

Look like a [bug in hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6776) . You could try saving the child first then parent and child relationship.